# How to take elements part successive from list in C#?

Tags: c#

I have integer list in C#. I need a method that, to give `startIndex` and `step` parameters and to take sublists from that. When reach to end, cross to begin of list. **like circle**

```
public List<int> GetSomeInt(List<int> mainList, int startIndex, int step )
{
  ...
}
```

For example, list elements are  **4, 2, 85, 6, 7, 89, 1, 0, 36, 47, 11, 75**.   I give `startIndex=3` and `step=5` to method and I get so results:

```
result1 - 6, 7, 89, 1, 0
result2 - 36, 47, 11, 75, 4
result3 - 2, 85, 6, 7, 89, 1
result4 - 0, 36, 47, 11, 75
result5 - 4, 2, 85, 6, 7
result6 - 89, 1, 0, 36, 47
........................
```

How I get so successive sub-elements of list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Queue` to do *round shift* then get the result by LINQ `Take`
:

```
public static List<List<int>> GetSomeInt(List<int> mainList, 
                                         int startIndex, int step)
{
    var queue = new Queue<int>();
    mainList.ForEach(queue.Enqueue);

    Enumerable.Range(0, startIndex)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(i => queue.Enqueue(queue.Dequeue()));

    var result = new List<List<int>>();

    while (true)
    {
        var list = queue.Take(step).ToList();
        list.ForEach(i => queue.Enqueue(queue.Dequeue()));

        if (result.Any(l => l.All(list.Contains)))
            break;

        result.Add(list.ToList());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code that will do what you are trying to achieve, you should not hand this code in, it is just a guide:

```
public List<int> GetSomeInt(List<int> mainList, int startIndex, int step )
{
    return mainList.Skip(startIndex).Take(step);
}
```

Here are the functions used: [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx)    [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx)

Your teacher(?) would probably **not** accept this answer, so I suggest you hard-code your own function that does the same as `Skip` and `Take`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: and list count = 10, startIndex = 9, step = 5. When index is over, will this go back to begin of list?

Comment: I don't think it will, but you could make your own method similar to the ones used in my post that will go back to the start of the list. One way you might do it is that you have a list containing `mainList` 10 times or so; so it will go back to the beginning of a list if you ask it to.